# Ansible force to use --limit and --tags when run playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using `ansible 2.9.4`. My goal is to deny run some playbook on all nodes by accident or without tags. This is my app.yaml:

```
  - hosts: all
    remote_user: root
    vars:
      server_domain: mydomain.com
      project_name: project
    tasks:
      - name: checking limit arg
        fail:
          msg: "you must use -l or --limit - when you really want to use all hosts, use -l 'all'"
        when: ansible_limit is not defined
        run_once: true
      - name: "suppress message if tag given"
        set_fact: suppress_message=yes
        tags: dev,test,prod
      - name: "message"
        fail:
          msg: "You didn't choose environment 'dev,test,prod'"
        when: suppress_message is not defined
    roles:
      - testrole
```

The problem is, when I am not use --limit option, the role `testrole` run successfully and then the error message occurs - too late if I already run it on all nodes.

Even when I specify tags `--tags "mytag"` it will not check if limit was specified.

By similar way I would like to force to use tags, so everytime when you run playbook, you should specify environment tag (`dev`, `test`, `prod`) - e.g ssh keys for different environments, configuration files, etc...

What I would expect from this, that If I not specified tag `dev`, `test` or `prod`,  the `suppress_message` would not be specified so next task with name `message` would fail with message "You didn't  choose environement".

The fact is, If I not specified any tag:
- `supress message` have state OK
- `message` is skipped

If I specify valid tag `--tags "dev"`:
- `supress message` have state OK
- `message` is not even mentioned (I would expect skipping)

If I specify "invalid tag" `--tags "dev123"`:
- `supress message` is not mentioned
- `message` is not mentioned

The solution for `limit` could be replace `- hosts: all` with  `- hosts: randomtext` so when no limit is specified there will be no match but what about tags/environments? I am quiet lost about how ansible works. The logic about this decisions what will run is quiet chaotic from this example.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example playbook that should achieve what you need to do.

1. Hosts are defined in a `myhosts` variable on the command line, the first task will abort the play if this variable is not set
2. Through use of the two “[special tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html)”, `always` and `never`, we can ensure that:

   - the above check *always* runs, and
   - the inclusion of your `testrole` *never* runs — unless `dev`, `test`, or `prod` tags are explicitly specified
3. There’s a helpful message before the inclusion of the `testrole`, so the user is not left confused if the play exits silently because of unset tags

```
- hosts: '{{ myhosts | default("localhost") }}'
  tasks:

  - name: Fail if hosts are not defined
    run_once: true
    fail:
      msg: >
        You must define hosts in the myhosts variable,
        e.g. `-e myhosts=foo.example.com` on the command line
    when: myhosts is undefined
    tags:
      - always

  - name: Helpful message
    run_once: true
    debug:
      msg: >
        This playbook does nothing unless the environment is specified with
        the `--tags` option on the command line (dev, test, or prod).
    tags:
      - always

  - name: Include role only when tags are specified
    include_role:
      name: testrole
    tags:
      - never
      - dev
      - test
      - prod
```

This would be then executed like so:

```
$ ansible-playbook app.yaml --extra-vars myhosts=foo.example.com --tags dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `tasks` to `pre_tasks`.

The order is `pre_tasks`, `roles`, `tasks`, `post_tasks`.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html

Playbook ordering is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is add a task to include the role.  So change

```
roles:
  - testrole
```

to

```
  - include_role: 
      name: testrole
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using tags like this -

```
tags:
  - dev,test,prod
```

Comment: The same result. I also tried `tags: [ dev, test, prod ]`, the same.